# Where to get Ahava Torah from Rav Zalman Pinchas Horowitz in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Where can I buy the sefer Ahava Torah of Rav Zalman Pinchas Horowitz in English?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this has never been translated to English.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the book is available in English?